# using networkx to run DAG of functions

Tags: python, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

Please view this graph:

[image: DAG sample]

every node here should be an image processing function applying to ndarray of an input image.
considering 3 path :

root>1>4

root>1>2>3

root>1>2>5

pencil me please, in networkx how can i use function as nodes? function a as node 1,function b as node 2,function c as node 3,and so

also how can i have all three output of 4,3,5 node as result while calculating function at node 1 only one time and function 2 only 2 times using networkx ?

```
import networkx as nx   

def a(ndarray_image):
    out = sharpen(ndarray_image)
    return (out)
def b(ndarray_image):
    out = lighten_r(ndarray_image)
    return (out)
def c(ndarray_image):
    out = lighten_g(ndarray_image)
    return (out)
def d(ndarray_image):
    out = lighten_b(ndarray_image)
    return (out)
def e(ndarray_image):
    out = smooth(ndarray_image,sigma=1.2)
    return (out)

G = nx.DiGraph()
nodes = ["root", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
edges = [("root", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("1", "4"), ("2","5"), ("2", "3")]
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Comment: Attaching data to nodes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698352/storing-and-accessing-node-attributes-python-networkx

Comment: Find all paths from root to leaf nodes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087010/python-networkx-simple-way-to-get-all-simple-paths-from-root-to-leaf