# pandas networkx generate all simple paths including internal nodes and root

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

New to graphs and I am struggling to work out how to show the path for each parent:child relationship in this table, AND include all intermediate nodes as well as the root on its own:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
'parent': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 5, 9: 5, 10: 5, 11: 5},
 'child': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 8, 7: 9, 8: 4, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12}})

# import networkx and build the graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# draw graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw_networkx(G,with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example graph]

The actual dataset is 100k rows, all integers, an unknown number of roots, currently up to 4 levels but could reach n levels deep.  This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```py
    result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'parent': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 5, 10: 5, 11: 5, 12: 5}, 
        'child': {0: '', 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 4, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12}, 
        'path': {0: '1', 1: '1,2', 2: '1,3', 3: '1,3,4', 4: '1,3,5', 5: '1,3,6', 6: '1,3,7', 7: '1,3,8', 8: '1,3,9', 9: '1,3,5,4', 10: '1,3,5,10', 11: '1,3,5,11', 12: '1,3,5,12'}, 
        'depth': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 4, 12: 4}})
    print(result.to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt="github"))
```

```
|   parent | child   | path     |   depth |
|----------|---------|----------|---------|
|        1 |         | 1        |       1 |
|        1 | 2       | 1,2      |       2 |
|        1 | 3       | 1,3      |       2 |
|        3 | 4       | 1,3,4    |       3 |
|        3 | 5       | 1,3,5    |       3 |
|        3 | 6       | 1,3,6    |       3 |
|        3 | 7       | 1,3,7    |       3 |
|        3 | 8       | 1,3,8    |       3 |
|        3 | 9       | 1,3,9    |       3 |
|        5 | 4       | 1,3,5,4  |       4 |
|        5 | 10      | 1,3,5,10 |       4 |
|        5 | 11      | 1,3,5,11 |       4 |
|        5 | 12      | 1,3,5,12 |       4 |
```

### all_simple_paths - excludes intermediate nodes:

all_simple_paths doesn't output the intermediate notes (stops at the end of the leaf):

- 1,3,5 or
- 1,3 or
- 1 on its own

source: [How to use recursion to record all routes in a parent child hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69342255/how-to-use-recursion-to-record-all-routes-in-a-parent-child-hierarchy)

```py
    # build graph
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    
    # Find roots of your graph (a root is a node with no input)
    roots = [node for node, degree in G.in_degree() if degree == 0]
    
    # Find leaves of your graph (a leaf is a node with no output)
    leaves = [node for node, degree in G.out_degree() if degree == 0]
    
    # Find all paths
    all_paths = []
    for root in roots:
        paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaves)  
        all_paths.extend(paths)
        
    # hacky output to df, convert float to int as strings
    out = pd.DataFrame(all_paths).fillna(-999999).astype(int).astype(str).replace('-999999', '')
    out.columns = out.add_prefix('level_').columns
    
    # concatenate levels to generate path
    out['path'] = (out.stack()
                    .groupby(level=0, sort=False)
                    .agg(','.join)
                    .values)
    # remove trailing commas
    out['path'] = out['path'].str.replace(r'\,+$', '', regex=True)
    print(out.to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt="github"))
```

```
|   level_0 |   level_1 | level_2   | level_3   | path     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|         1 |         2 |           |           | 1,2      |
|         1 |         3 | 4         |           | 1,3,4    |
|         1 |         3 | 5         | 4         | 1,3,5,4  |
|         1 |         3 | 5         | 10        | 1,3,5,10 |
|         1 |         3 | 5         | 11        | 1,3,5,11 |
|         1 |         3 | 5         | 12        | 1,3,5,12 |
|         1 |         3 | 6         |           | 1,3,6    |
|         1 |         3 | 7         |           | 1,3,7    |
|         1 |         3 | 8         |           | 1,3,8    |
|         1 |         3 | 9         |           | 1,3,9    |
```

### shortest_path and single_source_shortest_path both exclude the longer path to 4: 1,3,5,4:

```
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', 
    create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    paths_dict = nx.shortest_path(G, weight='distance')
    out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(paths_dict)
    print(out[1].to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt="github"))
```

```
| 1             |
|---------------|
| [1]           |
| [1, 2]        |
| [1, 3]        |
| [1, 3, 4]     |
| [1, 3, 5]     |
| [1, 3, 6]     |
| [1, 3, 7]     |
| [1, 3, 8]     |
| [1, 3, 9]     |
| [1, 3, 5, 10] |
| [1, 3, 5, 11] |
| [1, 3, 5, 12] |
```

source: [python networkx: simple way to get all simple paths from root to leaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087010/python-networkx-simple-way-to-get-all-simple-paths-from-root-to-leaf)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach with Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
root = df.loc[~df["parent"].isin(df["child"]), "parent"].unique()[0]  # 1

# Initialize column "path"
df["path"] = df["parent"].astype(str) + ", " + df["child"].astype(str)

# while there is at least one path not starting with 1
while not (df["path"].str[0] == str(root)).all():
    df["path"] = (
        df.apply(
            lambda x: df.loc[df["child"] == int(x["path"][0]), "path"].to_numpy()[0][
                :-1
            ]
            if df.loc[df["child"] == int(x["path"][0]), "path"].any()
            else "",
            axis=1,
        )
        + df["path"]
    )

# Add first row to df
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {"parent": [root], "child": [""], "path": [str(root)]},
        ),
        df,
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
)

new_df["depth"] = new_df["path"].str.split(", ").map(len)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
```

[image]